# Alpha Numeric Sorting

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have alpha numeric string .

i want to sort using SQL Server

```
select InvoiceNo from mytable sort by InvoiceNo


42047A3
42047A1
42047A2
```

Desired Sorting

```
42047A1
42047A2
42047A3
```

Comment: Your select should return results as desired (except it is not valid SQL)... Please post your source schema definition.

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to use proper sorting command in SQL Server.

```
Select InvoiceNo 
from mytable 
Order by InvoiceNo
```

This should get the data sorted in the correct order.